# Script to convert plain text to XML (e.g. CSV to XML)

Tags: xml

I am looking for a scripted way of converting plain text formats (e.g. CSV) to XML format. It is possible to do this kind of conversion using binary programming languages (e.g. Java, C#, etc) but I will likely have to deal with variations in the input format and would ideally like to be able to edit the "parser" remotely.

I have looked at XSL, which was my first choice, but from what I gather XSL for all its strengths cannot handle non-XML text files. It can of course output text files.

Any suggestions are welcomed. Ideally if the script could be as rich as XSL (e.g. basic functions like "round()" "trim()" etc) that would be even better!

Comment: Um, may I ask why? CSV and XML have totally different use cases, so while you certainly could do it, why would you want to?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the XQuery processor [Zorba](http://www.zorba-xquery.com) could be the right tool for you.

There is an extension module [csv2xml](http://www.zorba-xquery.com/doc/zorba-latest/zorba/xqdoc/xhtml/www.zorba-xquery.com_modules_csv2xml.html) included to convert from CSV to XML.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Gelatin](https://github.com/knipknap/Gelatin/wiki). It allows you to specify a syntax and convert text formats to JSON, XML, or YAML like so:

```
gel -f xml -s syntax.gel input.txt
```

(The content of syntax.gel is explained in the Gelatin wiki linked above.)